# Why is traditional HTTP not suitable for mobile devices

Tags: http, mobile, https, mobile-phones

I would like to understand why traditional HTTP is not suitable for mobile devices

Comment: What suggests that it's not?

Answer (score 1):

This is the article about Evolution of HTTP protocol.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Evolution_of_HTTP

If you mean version's of http protocol, read this article. there are some main diffrence between http v2 and http v1.1 but this is not true that these protocols are not suitable for mobile devices.